# Request Handling Capacity of springboot application with 1 instance

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, cpu, ram, disk

The number of requests that can be handled by a deployed spring boot application depends on configuration `server.tomcat.threads.max`. It is default as 200.

However, I believe the request handling capacity of an application also depends on various other capacities of the server, such as CPU, RAM, Disk capacity, etc.

So, the deployed instance of spring boot application with higher capacity should be able to handle more requests than lower capacity one. However, I am not clear how `server.tomcat.threads.max` decide this for different server sizes. Can somebody please clarify that?